# Intellij Python does not import from .pydevproject

Tags: python, python-2.7, intellij-idea

PyDev eclipse plugin creates two files a `.project` file and a `.pydevproject` file. The `.pydevproject` file contains all library references. Basically I list all my dependencies as

```
....
<path>\\basedir\nose\1.1.2-py27\lib</path>
<path>\\basedir\jenkinsapi\0.1.9\lib\jenkinsapi-0.1.9-py2.7.egg</path>
....
```

Unfortunately Intellij won't import these libraries from .pydevproject.

Question:

1. How can I force this?
2. I have the dependencies as  based strings and I can hand type them for IntelliJ but which file do I have to edit and where do I put this?
3. Also how do I alter the PYTHONPATH like in eclipse? In eclipse I can set the pythonpath to a list of UNC paths. Unfortunately I cannot* use the IntelliJ UI to choose a Python Intepreter and rely on Intellij defaulting mechanism to alter the paths (It is because my python is on a network share and relies on some native windows file system magic to workout where the bin files are. I would rather give IntelliJ a list of paths that make up the python interpreter)

Comment: It will not work with UNC paths in IDEA, map it to a drive letter and add to the Classpath tab of the Python SDK configuration.

Comment: @CrazyCoder So I can map them into a drive. But what would file do I need to edit to set these paths?

Comment: You can add these paths [here](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9563/20130322161825.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there a way where I can edit the text file directly? It is painful going through the UI and Idea tries* to expand that drive and mine is a huge NFS drive. Plus my NFS relies on ID_EXEC and the environment to show you new directories based on whether the underlying architecture is windows or linux. This works fine in eclipse though

Comment: [%CONFIG%](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)`\options\jdk.table.xml`.

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer? so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` for the additional modules can be configured in the [Python SDK settings](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9563/20130322161825.png) `Classpath` tab or directly in [%CONFIG%](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108)`\options\jdk.‌​table.xml` file.

Comment: If you want project specific JDKs http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html#procedure%0A____________to_configure_a_project_sdkproject_sdkaswrittenconfiguring_a_project_sdk

Comment: This changes the SDK for all projects. When I do a module specific SDK I don't see my SDK details in the *.iml file? Where is the module specific SDK details being stored?

Comment: SDK has always been a global configuration, project just references the SDK by its name.

Comment: So in Python I use project specific addins/libraries ex: nose or jenkins. Where do I configure them?

Comment: You can use the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html), will be stored in the `.iml` file.