# Intellij does not open python sources

Tags: python, intellij-idea

This may be a related question to [Intellij Python does not import from .pydevproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475913/intellij-python-does-not-import-from-pydevproject). I have Intellij 12.x with a python plugin and configured a 2.7.1 plugin SDK (Not sure if it matters that the Python SDK is in a network drive)

The IntelliJ seems to recognise my imports but it is not able to compile or drill down further to sources. This practically renders it useless for any development as I get loads of syntax errors.

For example if I do `import unittest` it does not show any error but when I drill into the unittest I can only see the first 20 characters or so of the unittest.py (snippet below).

```
"""
Python unit testing framework, based on Erich
```

I checked the file path and went to the file system and opened in notepad and I can see that it has all the contents. What is happening? When I type `unittest.` I expected to see all methods in the module but the IntelliJ says nothing to show (perhaps because it can't see teh source properly)

PS: In my Intellij Library and SDK I have added both classes and sources folders

Please observe that when you open unittest it opens the file as shown showing only the first 30 lines. If I open `M:\dist\....unittest\__init.py__` in a notepad I can see it has contents as I would expect to have it.

Comment: Do you use `Navigate` | `Declaration`? What file does it open? Please post the screenshot.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Added a screenshot :)

Comment: Try File | Invalidate caches and restart, see if you can reproduce it with a local drive.

Comment: What do you mean by a local drive? You mean a Python SDK installed locally?

Comment: Yes, exactly, when SDK files are not on the network drive.

Comment: It does work if it is on local drive. So are we saying it is not supported for SDKs on the network drive?

Comment: There is something specific about your remote network drive that breaks it. Normally it should work, but is not the officially supported configuration.